# Display data from MySQL to be used to dynamically change content through jQuery

Tags: jquery, mysql, dynamic

I am trying to read and display a menu and it's content dynamically through MySQL/PHP and jQuery. I have retrieved the menu name and displayed it properly on the page.

```
  $select_service_name = "SELECT serv_name FROM services";
    $query =  $conn->query($select_service_name);

foreach ($query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN) as $row) {
    echo '<li><a href="#">'. $row; '</a></li>';
 }
```

But now I want to fill the service description, displaying the first one read in, but storing the rest in div's that have

```
 display: none;
```

So I can use jQuery UI to hide/show the service description depending on which service the user clicks.

Any suggestions on how I can achieve this?

Thank you.

I have a menu:

```
ServiceName1 | ServiceName1 Description
ServiceName2 |
ServiceName3 |
```

etc, and use jQuery .show() .hide() I want to be able to display each of their descriptions depending on which servicename# is clicked. How do I do this using descriptions read from MySQl tables?

Comment: Use the jQuery functions `.show()` and `.hide()`?

Comment: Yes, but how do I store the data that I want to show and hide from MySQL, then display it depending on which menu item they select (which has also been read from mysql)

Comment: Perhaps you can be more specific in your question. I'm afraid I don't quite get the problem.

Comment: updated my question, any better?

Comment: Are you having problems with the MySql part, the HTML part, or the JS part?

Comment: I can read in the data from MySQL and know how to create HTML elements based off of that data - but I don't know how I should store it/create elements so I can THEN just jQuery to .show() .hide() depending on which menu item is clicked. I know how to do them all separately, but dont know how to bring them all together using data read from MySQL.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26310/discussion-between-dirk-mcquickly-and-thomas-speak)

Comment: can someone please help me on this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44120124/insert-dynamic-select-box-value-in-mysql-database-and-show-data-submitted-messag/44123272#44123272

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this:
PHP:

```
foreach ($query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN) as $row) {
   echo '<li class="row"><a href="#">' . $row . '</a><span class="description">' . $description . '</span></li>';
}
```

CSS:

```
.description{
  display: none;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".row a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".description").hide();
    $(this).parent("li").find(".description").show();
   });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jdfqS/2/

Also you dont need jQuery UI for this.. just jQuery

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using JSON to store the data in a data attribute. In PHP put the data you need into an object or array. Then use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to format it into a JSON string:

```
<div data-example='<?php echo json_encode($data); ?>'></div>
```

You can retrieve the data via [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) or [jQuery.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/):

```
$('[data-example]').each(function() {
    var data = $(this).attr('data-example');
    if (data) { 
        data = $.parseJSON(data);
    }
    // ...
});
```